# Avoiding [weak self] for simple operations?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, urlsession

For short-running operations, is it acceptable to avoid `[weak self]`? For example, `URLSession` will retain the closure from `dataTask(with:completion:)`:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let label = UILabel()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
      guard let data = data else { return }
      let decodedString = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.label.text = decodedString
      }
    }.resume()
  }
}
```

In this case, the closure captures `self` strongly, which means even if this `ViewController` is held in memory by the closure. `URLSession` will hold the closure until the data task is complete, which means the life cycle of the `ViewController` can potentially be extended until `dataTask` completes.

In this situation, should we use capture lists to avoid this behavior? Is my reasoning correct that there's no reference cycle here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the life cycle of the ViewController can potentially be extended until dataTask completes

So the question is whether that would be coherent. It might even be a *good* thing. If it would, then fine, and there’s no need for `weak self`, as there is no retain cycle because the
url session is shared.

But when the url session is an instance
 property and has a real delegate, things are much more complicated and
 you really can get a retain cycle, because the session retains its delegate which might be retaining the session.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about reference cycles, you usually don't get one when using URL requests. The thing is that the URL request finishes sooner or later (after several minutes) and you controller gets released. The reference cycle is only temporary and it won't cause a memory leak.

The question is whether you want to keep the controller in memory even if the user has already closed the controller and it won't be ever shown again. It won't probably cause any problems but it's still wasteful. You are holding to memory you don't need and that cannot be reused.

Also note that you might actually want to cancel the running request when the controller is dismissed to avoid sending/receiving data that is not necessary anymore.

In my opinion, you shouldn't worry that much about reference cycles and think more about ownership. A strong reference means that something is owned. The request has no reason to "own" the controller. It's the other way around - the controller owns and manages the request. If there is no ownership, I would use `weak` just for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my reasoning correct that there's no reference cycle here?

There is no reference cycle here. `ViewController` is not retaining the `dataTask` completion handler. You can think of this as iOS keeping a strong reference to both the view controller and the completion handler, and the completion handler also keeping a strong reference to the view controller. There is no strong reference from the view controller back to the completion handler, or to any chain of objects with a reference to the completion handler, so you are cycle-free. Look for this same pattern in `UIView.animate`, where you are again sending closures to iOS instead of storing them locally.

> For short-running operations, is it acceptable to avoid `[weak self]`?

The *duration* of the work is not a factor. The two pertinent questions are:

1. Does a cycle of references exist?
2. Will the cycle of references be broken?

Take this example:

```
class BadVC: UIViewController {
    private lazy var cycleMaker: () -> Void = { print(self) }

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        cycleMaker()
    }
}
```

`BadVC` here manages to create a reference cycle that will never be broken as soon as it loads its view. The fact that `cycleMaker()` will execute in nanoseconds does not save us from a memory leak.

---

Pragmatically, there is a third question:

3. Does this code avoid permanent reference cycles in a way that is difficult to understand, easy to break, or unreliable, so reference cycles are likely to emerge in the future due to misuse or modification?

You can break reference cycles manually. For example:

```
class StillBadVC: UIViewController {
    private lazy var cycleMaker: () -> Void = { print(self) }

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        cycleMaker()
    }

    func breakCycle() {
        cycleMaker = { }
    }
}
```

Here, we are in danger because `StillBadVC` has a strong reference to `cycleMaker` and `cycleMaker` captures a strong reference to `StillBadVC`. The cycle will be broken as long as someone remembers to call `breakCycle()`, at which point the view controller will remove its strong reference to `cycleMaker`, allowing `cycleMaker` to deallocate. However, the cycle will *not* be broken if someone forgets to call `breakCycle()`. Calling a method called `breakCycle()` is not usually a part of the contract for using a view controller, so we would expect `StillBadVC` to result in memory leaks in practice.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should use `[weak self]` here, not because of any risk of strong reference cycle, but simply because this closure exists solely to update a label. There is no point in writing code that deliberately keeps the view controller and its views in memory so you can update a label in a view that may have been dismissed and is no longer visible.

The `weak` keyword does not exist solely to avoid strong reference cycles, but rather to accurately represent the object ownership and manage object lifespans. You shouldn’t misrepresent the object ownership graph just for the sake of saving the few keystrokes associated with `[weak self]` capture list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already got your answer here. It's not a reference cycle.

But to build a systematic approach, my advice here is one more simpler. Forget thinking about leaks and stuff.

Think about **ownership** and **flow control** and then **memory-management**

- **Ownership:** Does this object need to own this other object? Should an object own its delegate? Should a subview own its parentiew? Does this request own this viewController?
- **Flow Control:** How soon do I want to de-allocate this object? Immediately or upon the view being removed from the screen?
- **Memory-management:** Is this a strong reference cycle?

This thought process not only helps you distinguish a true memory leak from something that isn't a leak. It also helps you design and read your code better and not just slavishly dump `[weak self]` all over the place.